# How did the PSP firmware 5.03 HEN-C exploit work?

Tags: exploit, firmware, jailbreak

On the historical PSP (PlayStation Portable) console on firmware version 5.03 there used to be a thumbnail-based exploit called HEN-C. It worked (under a race condition I presume since it didn't work every single time) by viewing a picture thumbnail of an splashed egg and a binary encoded (?) picture thumbnail, which was the payload itself I would presume. The exploit was used to load so called CFW (custom firmware) onto the device, which is basically a jailbroken/modified ROM.

My questions would be:

- I'm guessing the exploit used a flaw in the thumbnail parser, is that correct?
- How did it actually work?
- What was the exact flaw/programming mistake in the firmware that allowed this?
- Was there been any similar exploits on PC as well? (yes I've searched exploit-db.com already with no avail...)
- Is it possible to find the source code for it somewhere for historical reasons?

All I could find online, that is relevant (besides lots of YouTube videos with annoying buzzing in the background) is this source code for the newer procfw https://github.com/wicanr2/procfw, which appears to be irrelevant to the exploit apparently...

Comment: I've tried googling around a bit, and it seems there were multiple image exploits for the PSP. Given that it might be difficult to even pin down the correct exploit, I'm not sure whether you will get a good answer here (you might). Perhaps somebody at [retrocomputing.se] might know about it though.

Comment: The little I can tell you is:  Yes, it looks like the exploit targeted an image parsing library, although from what I can tell, it had to be chained with another exploit to gain kernel mode access. It wasn't necessarily a race-condition, more probably it was just a simple memory corruption. Memory corruption exploits can be unstable too, since the exact memory addresses cannot always be predicted exactly. And yes, there have been similar exploits with PCs too. Google "image parser exploits" and you will come across a few.

Comment: @nobody there appears to be a similar exploit on other firmware version, yes, but I think they only use the HEN name. Thank you for help, I will post a question there as well.